# Heroku - Django - the application loading process fails

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn

I've been browsing all the options and advice on the internet for 14 days and I can't help it, please help me how to run a properly installed application on Heroku? I'm creating an application on Windows10 and I can't run "gunicorn" there locally, unfortunately, how do I debug or where am I making a mistake...?

```
2022-03-08T17:05:18.069332+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

2022-03-08T17:05:18.091002+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-03-08T17:05:17.994885+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-03-08T17:05:24.550895+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn final_sda_project.wsgi --log-file -`
2022-03-08T17:05:26.835207+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-03-08T17:05:26.291724+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-08 17:05:26 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2022-03-08T17:05:26.292294+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-08 17:05:26 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:12794 (4)
2022-03-08T17:05:26.292350+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-08 17:05:26 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2022-03-08T17:05:26.296152+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-08 17:05:26 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2022-03-08T17:05:26.399828+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-08 17:05:26 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2022-03-08T17:05:26.442367+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-08 17:05:26 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924052+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-08 17:05:27 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924073+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924074+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924074+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924075+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924075+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924075+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924076+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924077+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924077+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924077+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924077+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924078+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924078+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924078+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924079+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924079+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924079+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924080+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924080+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924081+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924081+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924081+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 850, in exec_module
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924081+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924082+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/final_sda_project/wsgi.py", line 16, in 
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924082+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924082+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924082+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924083+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 19, in setup
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924083+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924083+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 87, in **getattr**
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924083+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924084+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 74, in _setup
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924084+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924084+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 183, in **init**
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924084+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924085+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924085+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924085+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924085+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924086+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924086+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924086+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 850, in exec_module
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924086+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924086+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/final_sda_project/settings.py", line 154, in 
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924087+00:00 app[web.1]: django_heroku.settings(locals())
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924087+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_heroku/core.py", line 69, in settings
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924087+00:00 app[web.1]: config['DATABASES']['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=MAX_CONN_AGE, ssl_require=True)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924088+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: config() got an unexpected keyword argument 'conn_max_age'
2022-03-08T17:05:27.924305+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-08 17:05:27 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935940+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-08 17:05:27 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935942+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935942+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935943+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935943+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935944+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935944+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935945+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935945+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935946+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935946+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935946+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935947+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935947+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935947+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935947+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935948+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935948+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935949+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935949+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935949+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935949+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935950+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 850, in exec_module
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935950+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935950+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/final_sda_project/wsgi.py", line 16, in 
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935950+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935951+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935951+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935951+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 19, in setup
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935951+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935952+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 87, in **getattr**
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935952+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935952+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 74, in _setup
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935953+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935953+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 183, in **init**
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935953+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935961+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935961+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935961+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935961+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935962+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935962+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935962+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 850, in exec_module
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935962+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935963+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/final_sda_project/settings.py", line 154, in 
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935963+00:00 app[web.1]: django_heroku.settings(locals())
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935963+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_heroku/core.py", line 69, in settings
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935964+00:00 app[web.1]: config['DATABASES']['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=MAX_CONN_AGE, ssl_require=True)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.935964+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: config() got an unexpected keyword argument 'conn_max_age'
2022-03-08T17:05:27.936163+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-08 17:05:27 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946046+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-08 17:05:27 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946048+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946049+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946050+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946050+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946051+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946051+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946051+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946052+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946052+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946053+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946054+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946054+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946054+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946060+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946060+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946061+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946061+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946062+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946062+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946062+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946063+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946063+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 850, in exec_module
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946063+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946064+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/final_sda_project/wsgi.py", line 16, in 
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946064+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946064+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946065+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946065+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 19, in setup
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946065+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946065+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 87, in **getattr**
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946066+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946066+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 74, in _setup
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946066+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946067+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 183, in **init**
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946067+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946067+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946068+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946068+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946068+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946069+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946069+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946069+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 850, in exec_module
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946070+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946070+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/final_sda_project/settings.py", line 154, in 
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946070+00:00 app[web.1]: django_heroku.settings(locals())
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946071+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_heroku/core.py", line 69, in settings
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946071+00:00 app[web.1]: config['DATABASES']['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=MAX_CONN_AGE, ssl_require=True)
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946071+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: config() got an unexpected keyword argument 'conn_max_age'
2022-03-08T17:05:27.946283+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-08 17:05:27 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2022-03-08T17:05:28.022283+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-08 17:05:28 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 10 was terminated due to signal 15
2022-03-08T17:05:28.026103+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-08 17:05:28 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 9 was terminated due to signal 15
2022-03-08T17:05:28.115867+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-08 17:05:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-03-08T17:05:28.116159+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-08 17:05:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2022-03-08T17:05:28.373912+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2022-03-08T17:05:28.561601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check **line 69** in your **settings.py** file, it is not getting the default database.

As you can see from the error code

```
08T17:05:27.946071+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_heroku/core.py", line 69, in settings 2022-03-08T17:05:27.946071+00:00 app[web.1]: config['DATABASES']['default'] =
```

Comment: I try many different variants and I can't handle that database. I tried [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-concurrency-and-database-connections] could you give me an advice please?